# Automatic Clustering With Hash/Map of Vectors in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, hash, dictionary, vector

I have the following values for example:

```
0 0 0 1 3 2
```

These values refers to cluster Ids, where the member of the cluster is the 
index of the vector. Hence we want to get this sort of output:

```
Cluster 0 -> 0,1,2
Cluster 1 -> 3
Cluster 2 -> 5
Cluster 3 -> 4
```

I tried the following construct but it doesn't seem to work:
What's the way to do it?

```
#include <iostream>      
#include <vector>        
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main  ( int arg_count, char *arg_vec[] ) {
    if (arg_count !=2 ) {
        cerr << "expected one argument" << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;      
    }

    string line;
    ifstream myfile (arg_vec[1]);

    map <int, vector <int> > CCTagMap;

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        // Skip First Line        
        getline(myfile,line);     

        while (getline(myfile,line) )
        {
            stringstream ss(line);    
            int CcId;
            int TagId = -1;           



            vector <int> Temp;        

            while (ss >> CcId) {      
                TagId++;
                cout << CcId << "-" << TagId <<  endl; 

                # this way to cluster doesn't seem to work
                CCTagMap.insert(make_pair(CcId,Temp.push_back(TagId)));
            }


        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    else  { cout << "Unable to open file\n";} 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is rewriting the vectors in the map each time.

Instead of:

```
CCTagMap.insert(make_pair(CcId,Temp.push_back(TagId)));
```

Try:

```
if ( CCTagMap.find( CcId ) == CCTagMap.end() )
{
    CCTagMap.insert(make_pair(CcId,vector<int>()));
}
CCTagMap[CcId].push_back( TagId );
```

Or even better,

```
map <int, vector<int> >::iterator iter = CCTagMap.find(CcId);
if ( iter == CCTagMap.end() )
{
    CCTagMap.insert(make_pair(CcId,vector<int>())).first->second.push_back( TagId );
}
else
{
    iter->second.push_back( TagId );
}
```

Comment: I cannot help but signalling that `map::insert(value_type)` returns the iterator, so you could assign to `iter` within the `if` block and only have one time the `->second.push_back(TagId)` bit (and no `else` clause)... but that's probably nitpick :P

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting the vector each time during insert. What you can do is something like:

```
map <int, vector <int> >::iterator iter = CCTagMap.find(CcId);
if(iter == CCTagMap.end())
{
  vector <int> Temp;  
  temp.push_back(TagId);
  CCTagMap[CcId] = temp;
}
else
{
  iter->second.push_back(TagId);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I supposed I would post a solution going for performance (remember, you should always try to optimize a soon as possible according to Knuth! unless I am mistaken ;) ).

```
CCTagMap[CcId].push_back(TagId);
```

Yeah, I really thought I should indicate this solution...

- save some typing
- more performant: only one lookup, instead of one for find and one for insertion. No temporary (though they would probably be optimized anyway).
- idiomatic ?

For a decomposed view of what's going on here:

```
std::vector<int>& CcVector = CcTagMap[CcId]; // [1]
CcVector.push_back(TagId);                   // [2]
```

1. `map::operator[]` is a mutating operator: it returns either the element stored for this key or inserts a newly default constructed element if none existed. It then returns a reference to the element (whether new or not).
2. We use the reference for a direct `push_back`, nice and clean.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? Instead of your `CCTagMap`, define:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > clusters;
```

then for each `TagId` and `CcId` do:

```
if (clusters.size() <= CcId)
  clusters.resize(CcId + 1);
clusters[CcId].append(TagId);
```